# How to disable compiler's options "-MT DOE.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/DOE.Tpo" automately generated by autoconf & automake

Tags: autoconf, automake

When I invoke a make command, the command reads (on the screen):

> ccppc -I. -I../../h -Wall -fno-builtin -fno-for-scope -mstrict-align 
>   -mcpu=604 -DCPU=PPC604 -mlongcall  -MT DOE.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/DOE.Tpo -c -o DOE.o DOE.c

I understand where `-I. -I../../h -Wall -fno-builtin -fno-for-scope -mstrict-align  -mcpu=604 -DCPU=PPC604 -mlongcall` comes from, because I defined them.

> AM_CFLAGS=-Wall -fno-builtin -fno-for-scope -mstrict-align  -mcpu=604
>   -DCPU=PPC604 -mlongcall AM_CPPFLAGS = -I../../h

However, I don't know where `-MT DOE.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/DOE.` comes from. I want to disable it.

I digged into the Makefile,and find the line related to `-MT DOE.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/DOE.`.

```
.c.o:
    $(COMPILE) -MT $@ -MD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.Tpo -c -o $@ $<
    $(am__mv) $(DEPDIR)/$*.Tpo $(DEPDIR)/$*.Po
```

I just want to remove `-MT $@ -MD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.Tpo`, for I get errors because of it.

Answer (score 2):

the `-M` flags are added by autoconf to enable dependency tracking.
you can disable them, by specifying by running:

```
 ./configure --disable-dependency-tracking
```

in general *autoconf* should figure this out by itself. did you specify the compiler (`ccppc` seems fairly non-standard to me) when running `configure` or did you only change to it when running `make`?